# Kinvey not working on iPhone and iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, kinvey

I'm using Kinvey's backend services accessing by their Javascript API. Initialisation of Kinvey works fine in any PC browser (Safari, FF, Chrome) and also on FF mobile and Chrome mobile. I got this error on iPhone's Safari and iPad's Safari only, console output:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Can't find variable: Kinvey
>   https://.html:22:15
>   l@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29380
>   https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29678

Here's the code showing the error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-html5-sdk-3.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://matthewcv.github.io/mobiledebug.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        console.log("before");

        // Init Kinvey
        Kinvey.init({
            appKey: '<yourAppKey>',
            appSecret: '<yourAppSecret>'
        });

        console.log("after");

    });
</script>

<body>

  <div>
      Show something
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm working with the latest iOS as well as the latest Javascript packages.

I wrote several times into Kinvey's forum but nobody seems to care of. So I try it here in hope someone knows the solution.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. I run this request without error. https://jsfiddle.net/remotesynth/pr69c47k/1/

Comment: Wow, thank you, that helped me! That tells me that I had to reset my iPhone and after that it worked! Emptying the cache didn't help. Some heavy screw up then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on remotesynth's comment I was sure that something screwed up my iPhone. After a complete reset of the device I could make it working too.